# jQuery UI sortable doesn't support floating divs?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm having a strange problem, that I've been trying to solve for too long. I hope you guys could help.

I have floating DIVs that I want to sort with jquery-ui-sortable. All goes well if I don't use a placeholder, but when I use one strange behaviour happens when the placeholder is in the top row on the last position.

Here's the example: http://oterosantos.com/test.html

If your screen is big enough to get all squares on a single row please resize the browser window.

Is this a jquery-ui bug?

Thanks,

-Ricardo

Comment: Hmm Chrome seems ok firefox I see what you mean though, taking a look.

Comment: @Nick: really? i'm seeing the same thing in chrome.

Comment: @David - Which version? I'm on 6.0.472.25

Comment: @Nick: granted, I'm on 5.0.375.125; still, this isn't something I'd expect to change. I haven't looked closely into the box model of the draggables and the placeholder, but if the latter really is smaller, this would be the expected behavior...?

Comment: @David - Yes it definitely would be...Chrome 6 has issues right now this may be one of them...for example Ctrl+F5 won't force recache, I have to navigate to the particular resource, which displays the cached version, refresh, *then* load the page, and that only works on the tab in question, all others use an old version...very, very annoying bugs atm :)

Comment: @Nick: the downside of being on the beta channel - hey wait that might be the *only* side of being on the beta channel. i switched to their stable releases quite recently myself, for exactly the reasons you've mentioned + a lot of crashes.

Comment: @David - I will be going that route...as soon as the built-in PDF reader lands in stable :)

Comment: I also have the same problem in Chrome. The solution by Nick solved it, thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to adjust the vertical padding on the `group_placeholder` style, instead of this:

```
padding: 20px;
```

Do this:

```
padding: 20px 20px 23px 20px;
```

Comment: This solved it! Thanks a lot! I played with the placeholder CSS a lot but didn't get it working. Cheers!